# can i integrate xtext project with an eclipse plugin project into one eclipse plugin project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

**i need to add xtext project to my plugin project to use the xtext editor and other features of xtext with my eclipse plugin. how do i do That ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open run configurations
2. plugins
3. Select all workspace enabled b